# How to turn on Auditing & Threat Detection for Azure SQL Database in ARM Template?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager

**Azure SQL Database Threat Detection** feature has been in General Preview since November 2015.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/threat-detection-public-preview/

However, I could not find out how can one turn on this feature and its dependency (**Azure SQL Database Auditing**) in the ARM template, neither in the Azure Quickstart Templates nor Azure Resource Manager Schema GitHubs links.

[azure-quickstart-templates](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/)

[azure-resource-manager-schemas](https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas)

Appreciate if anyone who knows can answer on this.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5):

Here are 2 sample templates:

First one, enable Auditing and Threat Detection for the whole SQL server.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "serverName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the new database server to create."
            }
        },
        "serverLocation": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The location of the database server."
            }
        },
        "administratorLogin": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The account name to use for the database server administrator."
            }
        },
        "administratorLoginPassword": {
            "type": "securestring",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The password to use for the database server administrator."
            }
        },
        "databaseName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the new database to create."
            }
        },
        "collation": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The database collation for governing the proper use of characters."
            }
        },
        "edition": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Standard",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The type of database to create. The available options are: Web, Business, Basic, Standard, and Premium."
            }
        },
        "maxSizeBytes": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "1073741824",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The maximum size, in bytes, for the database"
            }
        },
        "requestedServiceObjectiveName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "S0",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name corresponding to the performance level for edition. The available options are: Shared, Basic, S0, S1, S2, S3, P1, P2, and P3."
            }
        },
        "eventTypesToAudit": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue":"All",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The event type to audit."
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('serverName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
            "location": "[parameters('serverLocation')]",
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
            "properties": {
                "administratorLogin": "[parameters('administratorLogin')]",
                "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('administratorLoginPassword')]",
                "version": "12.0"
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "name": "[parameters('databaseName')]",
                    "type": "databases",
                    "location": "[parameters('serverLocation')]",
                    "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "edition": "[parameters('edition')]",
                        "collation": "[parameters('collation')]",
                        "maxSizeBytes": "[parameters('maxSizeBytes')]",
                        "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "[parameters('requestedServiceObjectiveName')]"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]"
                    ],
                    "location": "[parameters('serverLocation')]",
                    "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
                    "properties": {
                        "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
                        "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
                    },
                    "type": "firewallrules"
                },
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
                    "type": "auditingPolicies",
                    "name": "Default",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]",
                        "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'), '/databases/',parameters('databaseName'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "auditingState": "Enabled",
                        "storageAccountName": "<your-storage-account-name>",
                        "storageAccountKey": "<your-storage-account-key>",
                        "storageAccountResourceGroupName": "<your-storage-account-resource-group-name>",
                        "storageAccountSubscriptionId": "<your-storage-account-subscriptionid>",
                        "eventTypesToAudit": "parameters('eventTypesToAudit')"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
                    "type": "securityAlertPolicies",
                    "name": "Default",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]",
                        "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'), '/databases/',parameters('databaseName'))]",
                        "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'), '/auditingPolicies/Default')]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "state": "Enabled",
                        "disabledAlerts": "",
                        "emailAddresses": "abcd@efgh.com",
                        "emailAccountAdmins": "true"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Second one, enable Auditing and Threat Detection only for a specific database.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "serverName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the new database server to create."
            }
        },
        "serverLocation": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The location of the database server."
            }
        },
        "administratorLogin": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The account name to use for the database server administrator."
            }
        },
        "administratorLoginPassword": {
            "type": "securestring",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The password to use for the database server administrator."
            }
        },
        "databaseName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the new database to create."
            }
        },
        "collation": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The database collation for governing the proper use of characters."
            }
        },
        "edition": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Standard",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The type of database to create. The available options are: Web, Business, Basic, Standard, and Premium."
            }
        },
        "maxSizeBytes": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "1073741824",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The maximum size, in bytes, for the database"
            }
        },
        "requestedServiceObjectiveName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "S0",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name corresponding to the performance level for edition. The available options are: Shared, Basic, S0, S1, S2, S3, P1, P2, and P3."
            }
        },
        "eventTypesToAudit": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue":"All",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The event type to audit."
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('serverName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
            "location": "[parameters('serverLocation')]",
            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
            "properties": {
                "administratorLogin": "[parameters('administratorLogin')]",
                "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('administratorLoginPassword')]",
                "version": "12.0"
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "name": "[parameters('databaseName')]",
                    "type": "databases",
                    "location": "[parameters('serverLocation')]",
                    "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]"
                    ],
                    "properties": {
                        "edition": "[parameters('edition')]",
                        "collation": "[parameters('collation')]",
                        "maxSizeBytes": "[parameters('maxSizeBytes')]",
                        "requestedServiceObjectiveName": "[parameters('requestedServiceObjectiveName')]"
                    },
                    "resources":[
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
                            "type": "auditingPolicies",
                            "name": "Default",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'), '/databases/',parameters('databaseName'))]"
                            ],
                            "properties": {
                                "auditingState": "Enabled",
                                "storageAccountName": "<your-storage-account-name>",
                                "storageAccountKey": "<your-storage-account-key>",
                                "storageAccountResourceGroupName": "<your-storage-account-resource-group-name>",
                                "storageAccountSubscriptionId": "<your-storage-account-subscriptionid>",
                                "eventTypesToAudit": "parameters('eventTypesToAudit')"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
                            "type": "securityAlertPolicies",
                            "name": "Default",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'), '/databases/',parameters('databaseName'))]",
                                "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'), '/databases/',parameters('databaseName'), '/auditingPolicies/Default')]"
                            ],
                            "properties": {
                                "state": "Enabled",
                                "disabledAlerts": "",
                                "emailAddresses": "abcd@efgh.com",
                                "emailAccountAdmins": "true"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'))]"
                    ],
                    "location": "[parameters('serverLocation')]",
                    "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
                    "properties": {
                        "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
                        "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
                    },
                    "type": "firewallrules"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Note: Please don't forget to replace the information for the storage account.

Actually, Yoav Rubin has already answered your question in comment of [the blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/threat-detection-public-preview/). And, I have tested the answer, and have done some refinement.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! I will test this and if it works as expected I will accept this as answer.

Comment: This solution dont work for me. :( 
I find out, that ARM-Template-Schema contains no schema auditing and security: https://github.com/Azure/azure-resource-manager-schemas/blob/master/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/Microsoft.Sql.json

Comment: This deployment will use Table auditing which is now deprecated. How do we configure the deployment to use Blob auditing (and why is this not the default if Table is deprecated)?

Comment: Why do the auditingPolicies and SecurityAlertPolicies in the first sample have dependencies on the database itself? Shouldn't they only have a dependency on the SQL Server itself? The database would should automatically inherit them, right?

Answer (score 2):

There was a change in the last week which requires 2 more parameters to the securityAlertPolicies section:

```
"storageEndpoint": "https://<storage account name>.blob.core.windows.net/",
"storageAccountAccessKey": "<storage account key>"
```

This is so the service can write the alerts generated to your storage account as well.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, this just bit us with a "DataSecurityInvalidUserSuppliedParameter" error: "The parameter storageEndpoint cannot be null or empty.". Where was this change publicized? Where can we subscribe to be informed of changes like this?

Comment: This was released in improper way. It was suppose to take into account only for new API version but by mistake impacted all of them.

Comment: I would expect a blog post, or an email to affected users, or _something_ (!) to announce breaking changes like this beforehand or to publicize the change after a mistake like this one has been made, but we consistently get no warning or information. What do you recommend for watching for changes like these? A Github issues stream? An RSS feed somewhere? A blog you can point me to?

Comment: It should just not happened in the first place. it should have been released with new API version so old API will just work. I agree that proper communication was missing here.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Jack Zeng was close, but (at this point in time) you need auditingSettings to point to blob storage, since security alerting doesn't work with table storage.  So add  the following `auditingSettings` and `securityAlertPolicies` as child resources of the Microsoft.Sql/servers resource.

```
    {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "parameters": {},
        "variables": {},
        "resources": [
            {
                "name": "[parameters('sqlserverName')]",
                "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
                "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
                "properties": {},
                "resources": [
                    {
                        "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
                        "type": "auditingSettings",
                        "name": "Default",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            "[parameters('sqlserverName')]",
                            "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
                        ],
                        "properties": {
                            "State": "Enabled",
                            "storageEndpoint": "[concat('https://', parameters('storageAccountName'), '.blob.core.windows.net/')]",
                            "storageAccountAccessKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value]",
                            "storageAccountSubscriptionId": "[subscription().subscriptionId]",
                            "eventTypesToAudit": "All"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
                        "type": "securityAlertPolicies",
                        "name": "DefaultSecurityAlert",
                        "dependsOn": [
                            "[parameters('sqlserverName')]",
                            "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', parameters('storageAccountName'))]",
                            "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('sqlserverName'), '/auditingSettings/Default')]"
                        ],
                        "properties": {
                            "state": "Enabled",
                            "disabledAlerts": "",
                            "emailAddresses": "[parameters('securityAlertPolicyEmails')]",
                            "emailAccountAdmins": "Enabled",
                            "retentionDays": "10",
                            "storageEndpoint": "[concat('https://', parameters('storageAccountName'), '.blob.core.windows.net/')]",
                            "storageAccountAccessKey": "[listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Sources:

The blob storage auditing config is from here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/01/11/arm-template-turning-on-blob-auditing/

The threat detection resource config is from here (note that the storage auditing config from this example didn't work for me): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/01/11/arm-template-to-deploy-server-with-auditing-and-threat-detection-turned-on/